Sklearn : how to keep NaN values through OneHotEncoder?
INPUT
I have the following data:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'sex': ['female', 'male', np.nan], 'eye_color': ['blue', np.nan, 'brown']})
test_df

|   |    sex | eye_color |
|--:|-------:|----------:|
| 0 | female |      blue |
| 1 |   male |       NaN |
| 2 |    NaN |     brown |

CURRENT OUTPUT
I use OneHotEncoder and get the following:
ohe = OneHotEncoder(
    categories=[['female', 'male'], ['blue', 'brown', 'green']],
    handle_unknown="ignore",
    sparse_output=False,
).set_output(transform='pandas')
current_df = ohe.fit_transform(test_df)
current_df

|   | sex_female | sex_male | eye_color_blue | eye_color_brown | eye_color_green |
|--:|-----------:|---------:|---------------:|----------------:|----------------:|
| 0 |        1.0 |      0.0 |            1.0 |             0.0 |             0.0 |
| 1 |        0.0 |      1.0 |            0.0 |             0.0 |             0.0 |
| 2 |        0.0 |      0.0 |            0.0 |             1.0 |             0.0 |

DESIRED OUTPUT
How can I do to get the following output?
desired_df = pd.DataFrame({"sex_female": [1, 0, np.nan],
                           "sex_male": [0, 1, np.nan],
                           "eye_color_blue": [1, np.nan, 0],
                           "eye_color_brown": [0, np.nan, 1],
                           "eye_color_green": [0, np.nan, 0],
                          })
desired_df

|   | sex_female | sex_male | eye_color_blue | eye_color_brown | eye_color_green |
|--:|-----------:|---------:|---------------:|----------------:|----------------:|
| 0 |        1.0 |      0.0 |            1.0 |             0.0 |             0.0 |
| 1 |        0.0 |      1.0 |            NaN |             NaN |             NaN |
| 2 |        NaN |      NaN |            0.0 |             1.0 |             0.0 |

Ultimately, I would like to obtain this:
ultimately_df = SimpleImputer().set_output(transform="pandas").fit_transform(desired_df)
ultimately_df

|   | sex_female | sex_male | eye_color_blue | eye_color_brown | eye_color_green |
|--:|-----------:|---------:|---------------:|----------------:|----------------:|
| 0 |        1.0 |      0.0 |            1.0 |             0.0 |             0.0 |
| 1 |        0.0 |      1.0 |            0.5 |             0.5 |             0.0 |
| 2 |        0.5 |      0.5 |            0.0 |             1.0 |             0.0 |


If you're willing to use a different package, the OneHotEncoder from category_encoders has an option handle_unknown="return_nan" that does precisely that.
I don't think you can manage this behavior out of sklearn; you'd have to write a custom transformation, either ad hoc, or a custom class (either as a second step to the OHE, or extending the OHE class).
